# Logarithm, exponentiation, addition, and multiplication,

Tags: logarithms, arithmetic, exponential-function, math-history, philosophy

If the logarithm converts multiplication to addition, thus simplifying mathematics, does exponentiation, converting addition to multiplication, "complicate" mathematics?  I've only ever seen arguments for the former but never a discussion about the latter.  So, do we not consider exponentiation as a "bad" thing in mathematics?

Thanks,

Comment: I would not consider exponentiation as a "bad" thing in mathematics. I would also not consider conversion from multiplication to addition generally "simplifying mathematics". There are some times when using the properties of the logarithm function are useful, and there are times when using the properties of the exponential function are useful.

Comment: @D.Hutchinson While you are right that the purpose of mathematics is to make concepts as simple as possible, this does not mean that higher-level concepts are *"bad'* for being higher-level. Sometimes there is a genuine need to use them to express concepts, and we need to use notations like exponentials to express them.

Comment: On analytic functions $z \mapsto \exp(z)$ (analytic everywhere) is much easier than $z \mapsto \log (z)$ (singularity at $0$ and branch cut)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

John Napier invented logarithms as a tool for faster more accurate multiplication. Navigation at sea uses spherical trigonometry, and that  involves much multiplication. But there is much complicated work in preparing a table of logarithms, so the use of a table of logarithms to do multiplication is not really  less complicated. It just reduces the number of errors of the kind that humans make, provided that the table of logarithms is itself free of errors. In the pre-computer era this was itself a difficulty.

Comment: Have a look into tropical algebra. In terms of probabilistic models the semiring given by the nonnegative real numbers is replaced by the tropical algebra. This yields famous algorithms like Viterbi, Felsenstein and Needleman-Wunsch.